# how to set radio button to center align

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm new to `Android` development my problem is that, I want to align these radio button to the center of (now its left aligned) I didn't use any radio group in my program.

My XML code is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dassd.androidapp.Activity8">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_marginRight="138dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Sr.no" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Name" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gender"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Gender" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Age (in years" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="male" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="female" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="1" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" />

        <RadioButton

            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:checked="false" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="2" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="3" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText12"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="4" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText16"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="5" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText17"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton9"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText20"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="6" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton11"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton12"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText24"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="7" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText25"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton13"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton14"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText28"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>


</TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="8" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText29"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >


        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton15"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton16"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText32"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>


</TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="9" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton17"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton18"
            android:checked="false" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText36"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        </EditText>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dip"
        android:text="10" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText37"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton19"

            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/radioButton20"
            android:checked="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText40"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" >
        </EditText>
</TableRow>


</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Could you please tell me the names and ages of all members in the age group of 8-34 years? Please start from the youngest member. Also tell me their gender "
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="764dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="764dp" />
```

Comment: screenshot Sir thanks

Comment: what happens when you set android:layout_width = "match_parent" then android:gravity="center"

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't allow me to share screen shots .. coz of reputation problem

Comment: True, what happens when you set android:layout_width = "match_parent" then android:gravity="center"

Comment: added those code .. but no affects... the same output..

Comment: How bout this, I removed layout_weight.. apply it in all radio button. try

<RadioButton

            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" />

Comment: how do you want give an example

Comment: @Sheychan Do i need to change all the radio buttons.. I h'd  tried by changing single row  but  it not in an aligned display

Comment: yah but wait did you try and it went center???

Comment: @Sheychan My table is 10*5 model .It has 20 radio button ie, 2 radio button in a row . For a sample i changed the first row  as per ur code .. but  its not aligned properly

Comment: how about when u changed everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code in `radioButton` Tag

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

try thes link
http://www.coderanch.com/t/614667/Android/Mobile/align-radio-button
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

try this piece of code:

```
<RadioButton android:text=""
  android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
  android:checked="false"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center" 
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is insert your `RadioButton` inside a `LinearLayout` element, on which attribute `gravity` is set to `center`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
                android:checked="false" />

</LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center" >  

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text=""
                android:id="@+id/radioButton10"
                android:checked="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```